# Change ref color of on the 'List of Figures'

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, color

In my 'List of Figures' Chapter the data is listed in red, and with a reference to
appropriate part of the pdf file. I suppose this is due to

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=black,pagebackref]{hyperref}
```

Note that red numbers are used to point to equations, and I would not like to change them. Also, it looks nice with `\pagebackref`. However, my List of Figures
looks awkward, and I would like it to be written in plain black, possibly surrounded by blue rectangle. If that is not possible, then it is acceptable to make it just black, without any hyperref. How could this be achieved?

Comment: That should be possible with `\bgroup \hypersetup{linkcolor = black} \listoffigures \egroup` (or without the grouping and an additional `\hypersetup{linkcolor = red}` after the listoffigures.

Comment: Your first proposition worked. However, could I leave the red rectangle that is surrounding the entries?

Comment: Yes, but... - please see my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is possible with

```
\bgroup
\hypersetup{linkcolor = black}
\listoffigures
\egroup
```

or more compact (but maybe not as obvious) with brackets for grouping

{\hypersetup{linkcolor = black} \listoffigures}

or alternatively without the grouping but an additional `\hypersetup{linkcolor = red}` after the `\listoffigures`:

```
\hypersetup{linkcolor = black}
\listoffigures
\hypersetup{linkcolor = red}
```

The [hyperref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package uses either `colorlinks=true`, i.e. the links are shown in some other colour than black, or `colorlinks=false`, in which case the text of the links is black (or whatever colour is set e.g. with `\color`) and there is a coloured rectangle around it. The `colorlinks`-option cannot be changed with `\hypersetup`.

Nevertheless it is possible to do this:

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=false,linkbordercolor=red,...]{hyperref}
```

to get red rectangles around the links,

```
\listoffigures

\hypersetup{linkbordercolor = white}
```

to get rid of the rectangles after the list of figures,

```
{\color{red}\ref{something}}
```

to get red links (needed for each & every link!). Probably something like

```
\newcommand*{\myref}[1]{{\color{red}\ref{#1}}}
```

in the preamble (after loading the `hyperref` package) and using `\myref` instead of `\ref` would be easier, maybe even re-defining `\ref`.

You would also need to do this colour-management for the other types of links!

(BTW: For blue rectangles it is `linkbordercolor=blue`.)

Using the [xcolor](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) package it is also possible to use

```
\colorlet{foo}{red}
\colorlet{red}{blue}

\listoffigures

\colorlet{red}{foo}
```

The links (either text or rectangle) in the `\listoffigures` would be printed in blue, and the links afterwards in red again. The question "How do I combine link-colouring and link-borders with the hyperref-package?" is probably best asked as new question in my humble opinion.

Comment: I believe a third possibility to set `\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}` locally would be to enclose it in brackets as in
`{
\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
\listoffigures
}`
so you don't have to set the color back or to use the `bgroup`, right?

Comment: @fidekild: Yes, as I did in `{\color{red}\ref{something}}`. Added "grouping by brackets" to the answer, thanks for pointing out!